# Crystal Report XI error in formula using Basic Syntax " 'THEN' Missing "

Tags: vba, if-statement, crystal-reports

I am getting an error '`THEN`' Missing
If I play around with the formatting I eventually will get it to highlight the ELSE IF all the way down to formula = line.

I have attached screenshots to show what I mean with the highlight.
I have come to realize that crystal report is finicky about formatting sometimes, can anyone provide insight or the correct approach to get this formula working?

Thanks in advance!

```
 dim qtyavailable as number



IF ISNULL({HB_AVAILABLE_QTY_SKU\\.AVAIL}) 
    THEN qtyavailable = 0

        ELSE IF ({HB_AVAILABLE_QTY_SKU\\.AVAIL}) = 0
                AND ({INVENTORY_PART\\.PRIME_COMMODITY}) 
                LIKE FLY* OR SPC* 
        THEN "NA" 

            ELSE IF {SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC\.QTY_REQUIRED} = {SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC\.QTY_ASSIGNED} 
            THEN qtyavailable = {HB_AVAILABLE_QTY_SKU\\.AVAIL}+{SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC\.QTY_ASSIGNED}

                ELSE qtyavailable = {HB_AVAILABLE_QTY_SKU\\.AVAIL}
                END IF

        END IF

END IF

formula = qtyavailable
```

[image: else if error crystal reports]

Comment: Are you really using VBA, or did you mean to select the VB.NET tag? If VB.NET, please take a moment to EDIT your question and adjust the tags - then the right people will see your question :-)

Comment: Hey @CindyMeister I included the VBA tag since crystal reports uses the visual basic syntax its formula based reporting. I do appreciate you reaching out and verifying that info though! Thanks!

Comment: Visual Basic (as in VB.NET or classic VB) is not the same as VBA (Visual Basic for APPLICATIONS - VB that's integrated into an Application interface). I've never heard of Crystal Reports being embedded in an application, although I have heard of it being used with VB languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the "THEN" be on the same line as the "IF" so a modified pseudocode of your if statement would be similar to:

```
IF ISNULL({foo}) THEN 
    qtyavailable = 0
ELSE 
    IF ({foo}="0" AND {foo} LIKE "1") THEN 
        ' do nothing
    ELSE 
        IF {foo} = {bar}  THEN 
            qtyavailable = 2
        ELSE 
            qtyavailable = 3
        END IF
    END IF
END IF
```